# Showing only entire units on ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i was making a chart today - to test it out - and I was thinking if it is possible to show only entire units on the side of the chart ? (Like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, and so on...)
I'm using ChartJS

Here's a screen :
[image]

(The units are at the left, near the "Value")

PS: excuse my bad English, I'm french.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in options to override the scale like so

```
...
scaleOverride: true,
scaleSteps: 10,
scaleStepWidth: 1,
scaleStartValue: 0,
...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3kvb8ycy/

---

If you don't know the upper limit of your data, then you can either calculate the above before you initialize the chart and set it (boring :-)) or do something where you format the scale label not to show the scale label when you don't have a whole number

```
new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
  integersOnly: true,
  scaleLabel: function(d) {
    if (parseInt(d.value) === Number(d.value))
      return d.value
    else
      return '';
  }
});
```

Which covers pretty much most cases, except for when all your values are below 1 and none of them are close to one - in this case you don't see any scale labels.

Now you could simply put in an extra value at the end your data array (i.e. without a corresponding label and that would force the scale to go up to 1), but that would pull up the line after the last line (a bit). This is how that looks like

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [0.65, 0.2, 0.80, 0.81, 0.56, 0.55, 0.8, 1]
        }
    ]
};
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wufLjajg/

---

But we can do one better and just move this dummy point to a dummy series and fill the rest of the series with null (Chart.js does not plot null values, nor show it in tooltips)

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [0.65, 0.2, 0.80, 0.81, 0.56, 0.55, 0.8]
        },
        {
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 1]
        }
    ]
};
```

and then you're gold (since the last point is off the chart you won't even see it's tooltip).

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kzaxtmdq/

Comment: does this still work in the 2.0 version I remember seeing that there was an issue that this wasn't taken into consideration but might have been fixed now

Comment: This works, but isn't perfect. Try putting 100 as a value, then it won't show up (out of screen). It's normal as result of your script, but isn't what I want

Comment: @Quince - don't know if there is something equivalent in 2.0 yet. Couldn't find anything in the 2.0.0-beta documentation - there was something in the 2.0.0-alpha code (override.steps... etc.) but a quick search didn't turn up anything in the 2.0.0-beta scale files (but I'm not that familiar with the code to say that for sure)

Answer (score 1):

i have this issue too , but when i looked the code of chartjs i could understand what happened, it's happend because the min and the max value in the dataset was between 1 only if dataset has some value bigger than 1 it will show just the integer part , see the snippet:

```js
var lineChartData1 = {
    "datasets": [{
        "data": [
            "0.5",
            "0.2",
            "0.9",
            "0.4",
            "0.3",
            "0.2",
            "0.5",
            "0.7",
            "0.5",
            "1"],
            "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
            "fillColor": "rgba(155,220,220,0.5)",
            "pointColor": "rgba(155,220,220,1)",
            "strokeColor": "rgba(155,220,220,1)"
    }],
        "labels": [
        "2013-01-01",
        "2013-01-04",
        "2013-01-15",
        "2013-02-03",
        "2013-03-25",
        "2013-04-03",
        "2013-04-14",
        "2013-05-27",
        "2013-05-27",
        "2013-08-03"]
};

var lineChartData2 = {
    "datasets": [{
        "data": [
            "0.5",
            "0.2",
            "3",
            "0.4",
            "0.3",
            "2.2",
            "2",
            "0.7",
            "0.5",
            "1"],
            "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
            "fillColor": "rgba(155,100,220,0.5)",
            "pointColor": "rgba(155,100,220,1)",
            "strokeColor": "rgba(155,100,220,1)"
    }],
        "labels": [
        "2013-01-01",
        "2013-01-04",
        "2013-01-15",
        "2013-02-03",
        "2013-03-25",
        "2013-04-03",
        "2013-04-14",
        "2013-05-27",
        "2013-05-27",
        "2013-08-03"]
};


var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData1);
var myLine2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData2);
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js"></script>

<body>
    <div>
      <h3>Only one Integer</h3>
      <canvas id="canvas1" height="200" width="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>More then one Integer</h3>
      <canvas id="canvas2" height="200" width="400"></canvas>  
    </div>
</body>
```

I hope be useful.

Comment: I was thinking about that, so I'm realising this isn't "really" a problem anymore. Thanks !